# I can't log in to the Django application using the server and I don't know why

Tags: python, django

Currently I am trying to create an application using Django. I have made a CustomUsers class and all that. But when I try to login, it does not work.

I have the following models:

```py
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("The Email field must be set")

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, username=username, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email=None, username=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')
        if email is None:
            raise ValueError('The Email field must be set for superuser.')

        return self.create_user(email, password, username, **extra_fields)


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, default='')
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    coins = models.ManyToManyField('Coin', through='UserCoin')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
```

The following login view:

```py
def user_login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('dashboard')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                next_url = request.POST.get('next')
                if next_url:
                    return redirect(next_url)
                else:
                    return redirect('dashboard')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Invalid username or password.')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
        next_url = request.GET.get('next')
        if next_url:
            form.initial['next'] = next_url
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'You need to log in.')

    return render(request, 'FinApp/login.html', {'form': form})
```

And the following login backend:

```py
from .models import CustomUser
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password


class CustomUserBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=username)
        except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password) and user is not None:
                return user
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return CustomUser.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

The problem is that the passwords aren't hashed when I register them. Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: "it doesn't work": how exactly? Does it crash? Do you get "permission denied"; or perhaps "User not recognized"; something else? What do you see on the webpage? What output do you get in the terminal while running the development server? How did you create the user? You "have searched a lot": what have you (re)searched; what  options have you excluded? Your question needs many more debugging details to be answerable.

Comment: When using the development server, you can litter your program with print functions, printing out the value of various variables. That way, you can see what is and what is not happening in e.g. the `user_login` view. That'll be useful to know.

Comment: @9769953 It keeps giving the error I built in: invalid username or password. I think it either has to do with the authentication process or the login view itself. The user is created through for example createsuperuser or the register page. I added the post with the registry page. I will also try to search for some more debugging info. I'm new to this kind of programming so excuse me for not stating the question clearly.

Comment: @9769953 So the value for user in the user_login is None even though the right password and username are retrieved.

Comment: If you have the admin site enabled, you can look there to see if the user actually exists. Or, you can always access the database directly (e.g., from the terminal) and query the respective table to see if the user exists.

Comment: You can directly print the `username` and `password` before the `authenticate` line in your views (when using the development server) to see what the values are, and if they match what you are expected.

Comment: @9769953 they match... I ultimately wrote some printing statements in my backend authenticator. It correctly retrieves the expected password and the given password is the same as the expected password. However, when it is going through the ````user.check_password(password)```` part it comes back as False... That is the reason the login fails.

Comment: So the passwords don't match. Then you should look at your user creation procedure; or consider you simply are using the incorrect password.

Comment: @9769953 I found the reason, but do not know how to fix it. For some reason the ````user.set_password(password)```` does not hash the passwords and check_password does look for the hashed password. Any idea how I can change this?

Comment: Check which part of your settings.py you have changed.

Comment: How have you deduced that `set_password()` doesn't hash the password: did you look in the database? Or just checked `user.password`? Also, did you set any value for `PASSWORD_HASHERS` in `settings.py`?